# React js error linking js with html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed facebook's tutorial to learn react. I used **npm create-react-app** to create a react app. Html files are in a folder called public . JS and CSS files are in a folder called src.

This is my **index.html:**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="login.html">Link</a>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my **index.js**:

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <App  name="Sumanth Jois"/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html works fine . `<App/>` is being rendered on to the screen.I have another file which login.html.

This is **login.html:**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my **login.js** :

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



ReactDOM.render(
  <App  name="Sumanth Jois"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But this time login.html is display nothing it's empty. Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong? I am stuck with this for hours now.

Comment: I doubt that you haven't configured your transpiler.

Comment: @mehulmpt That wouldn't prevent `login.html` from rendering, and likely the app wouldn't render into `index.html`'s DOM if there was a build issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton you're right. To op: what do you get in the console?

Comment: > Unexpected token on line one login.js

Comment: What are those spaces before the import statement? Actual spaces? Or some random Unicode thing that looks like a space?

Comment: no they just happend to occur when I pasted the code here